# How suppress new paragraph after item's description in enumerate-with-description?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

The command `\descitem` below allows an item in an `enumerate` list to include a description. (Sorry, I cannot find the source of that definition now at tex.stackexchange.) The idea is to allow an optional argument to items in an `enumerate` list similar to the way one has optional arguments to a `theorem` or theorem-like environment with `amsthm`.

After an ordinary `\item`, a blank line does *not* immdiately start a new paragraph. Good!

But after a `\descitem`, a blank line unfortunately *does* cause a new paragraph to start. Bad! **How can this be fixed?**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{penum}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[penum,1]{%
  label= \sffamily\upshape(\arabic*),
  ref={\arabic*}, 
  widest=99,
}
\newcommand\descitem[1][]{\item{\sffamily\MakeUppercase#1. }}

\begin{document}
\begin{penum}

\item

An ordinary item: no new paragraph printed, despite preceding blank line.

\descitem[number two]

An item with a description: blank line causes new paragraph.

\descitem[three]
\label{it:three}

A labeled item with a description: ditto.
 
\end{penum}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate with description]

Thus, I'm trying to make the behavior of `\descitem` the same as `\item` in this regard: a blank line after the line with the command not creating a new paragraph. So I'm asking how to modify \descitem so as to not to into vertical mode there.

The situation is akin to that with an optional argument to a `theorem` environment: after `\begin{theorem}[something-about-it]` a blank line immediately following does *not* cause a new paragraph to begin.

Why don't I simply avoid the blank line? Because having the blank line after a `\descitem[...]`, like having one after an ordinary `\item`, makes it much easier to locate items when I'm rewriting or editing source.

Comment: Don't insert a blank line between`\item` and the text.

Comment: Your `\descitem` doesn't provide its optional argument as an argument for `\item`, but as text that should be put there, so naturally after you started a paragraph a `\par` (or blank line) will start a new paragraph.

Comment: I"m trying to make the behavior of `\descitem` the same as `\item` in this regard: a blank line after the line with the command *not* creating a new paragraph. So I'm asking how to modify `\descitem` so as to *not* to into vertical mode there.

Comment: `\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}` could work.

Comment: @Skillmon: Alas, that simple fix does *not* work when there is also a `\label`, as in the 3rd item I showed.

Comment: back to comment 1. Or put a `%` in the blank line if it's just about the visual clarity of your sources. I'd rather not try and force that behaviour with some hacky solution...

Comment: @Skillmon: I understand your point.

Comment: @Skillmon: Is there a way to modify your `\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}` so as to avoid creating a new paragraph also if there is a `\label{....}` either immediately after (on the same line as) the optional `[...]` to `\descitem" or on a new line immediately after the `[...]`?

Comment: `\newcommand\gobblepar{\@ifnextchar\label{\gobblepar@label}{\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}}}\newcommand\gobblepar@label[2]{\label{#2}\gobblepar}`.

Comment: @Skillmon: One problem: when the `\descitem` does have a `\label{...}` , I get extra horizontal space after the period that follows the description.

Comment: then back to comment 1... But without taking a more thorough look (meaning without compiling anything), I don't see where this extra space should come from. The code from my comment doesn't introduce any, and `\@ifnextchar` gobbles spaces until the implicit `\par` token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest an obscure solution. We measure the width of the `\descitem` parameter, then we leave the horizontal mode and return to the vertical mode. The first letter of the next text opens horizontal mode again. The `\everypar` moves the text to the appropriate horizontal position and the negative `\vskip`s move it to the appropriate vertical position.

```
\def\descitem[#1]{\par
   \setbox0=\hbox{\sffamily\MakeUppercase#1. }
   \item{\sffamily\MakeUppercase#1. }\par
   \everypar={\hskip\wd0 \everypar={}}
   \nobreak\vskip-\parskip \vskip-\baselineskip
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd still not recommend doing this, but the following implements the `\gobblepar` macro from my earlier comment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepar
  {\@ifnextchar\label{\gobblepar@label}{\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}}}
\newcommand\gobblepar@label[2]{\label{#2}\gobblepar}
\makeatother

\newlist{penum}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[penum,1]{%
  label= \sffamily\upshape(\arabic*),
  ref={\arabic*}, 
  widest=99,
}
\newcommand\descitem[1][]{\item{\sffamily\MakeUppercase#1. }\gobblepar}

\begin{document}
\begin{penum}

\item

An ordinary item: no new paragraph printed, despite preceding blank line.

\descitem[number two]

An item with a description: blank line causes new paragraph.

\descitem[three]
\label{it:three}

A labeled item with a description: ditto.
 
\end{penum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After the "number two" `\descitem` and :An item with a description: blank line...." insert an ordinary item: `\item
[blank line] \textsf{Number two.} An item with a description.` and now you'll see, by comparision, there is extra horizontal space after "Number two" in the `\descitem`

Comment: @murray that's the bigger spacefactor after the period that gets additionally stretched because the line is borderline short. If you use a control space after the period instead of a normal space you'll get normal spacing if that's what you're after. Also if you use `\descitem{Number two} An item with a description.` you'll get the same spacing as in your `\item` usage. Your line doesn't need stretching, unlike the line with `: blank line causes new paragraph.` after it.